# Dynamically create a two dimensional Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

Can someone show me the javascript I need to use to dynamically create a two dimensional Javascript Array like below?

**desired array contents:**

```
[["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"],["test6","test7","test8","test9","test10"]]
```

**current invalid output from alert(outterArray):**

```
"test6","test7","test8","test9","test10","test6","test7","test8","test9","test10"
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
var outterArray = new Array();
var innerArray = new Array();
var outterCount=0;
$something.each(function () { 
   var innerCount = 0;//should reset the inner array and overwrite previous values?
   $something.somethingElse.each(function () {
        innerArray[innerCount] = $(this).text();
        innerCount++;
   }
   outterArray[outterCount] = innerArray;
   outterCount++;
}
alert(outterArray);
```

Comment: What does the input look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to map the array of text for each `$something` element into an outer jagged array.  If so then try the following

```
var outterArray = [];
$something.each(function () { 
  var innerArray = [];
  $(this).somethingElse.each(function () {
     innerArray.push($(this).text());
  });
  outterArray.push(innerArray);
});

alert(outterArray);
```

Answer (score 9):

This is pretty cut and dry, just set up a nested loop:

```
var count = 1;
var twoDimensionalArray =[];

for (var i=0;i<2;i++)
{
  var data = [];
  for (var j=0;j<5;j++)
  {
    data.push("Test" + count);
    count++;
  }

  twoDimensionalArray.push(data);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible approach is to use raw objects, they are used in a similar way than dictionaries. Dynamically expendables and with more options to define the index (as string).

Here you have an example:

```
var myArray = {};
myArray[12]="banana";
myArray["superman"]=123;
myArray[13]={}; //here another dimension is created
myArray[13][55]="This is the second dimension";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep track of array lengths yourself; the runtime maintains the ".length" property for you. On top of that, there's the `.push()` method to add an element to the end of an array.

```
    // ...
    innerArray.push($(this).text());
  // ...
  outerArray.push(innerArray);
```

To make a new array, just use `[]`:

```
innerArray = []; // new array for this row
```

Also "outer" has only one "t" :-)

Answer (score 1):

[[SEE IT IN ACTION ON JSFIDDLE]](http://jsfiddle.net/gPKKG/2/) If that $something variable is a jQuery search, you can use .map() function like this:

```
var outterArray = [];

var outterArray = $('.something').map(function() {

    // find .somethingElse inside current element

    return [$(this).find('.somethingElse').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get()]; // return an array of texts ['text1', 'text2','text3']

}).get(); // use .get() to get values only, as .map() normally returns jQuery wrapped array

// notice that this alert text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6 
alert(outterArray);​ 

// even when the array is two dimensional as you can do this: 
alert(outterArray[0]); 
alert(outterArray[1]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="something">
    <span class="somethingElse">test1</span>
    <span class="somethingElse">test2</span>        
    <span class="somethingElse">test3</span>           
</div>
<div class="something">
    <span class="somethingElse">test4</span>
    <span class="somethingElse">test5</span>        
    <span class="somethingElse">test6</span>           
</div>
```

Here you can see it working in  a jsFiddle with your expected result: http://jsfiddle.net/gPKKG/2/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently while working on a Google Spreadsheet and came up with an answer similar to BrianV's:

```
  // 1st nest to handle number of columns I'm formatting, 2nd nest to build 2d array   
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    tmpRange = sheet.getRange(Row + 1, Col + i, numCells2Format); // pass/fail cells
    var d2Arr = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < numCells2Format; j++) {
      // 1st column of cells I'm formatting
      if ( 1 == i) {
        d2Arr[j] = ["center"];
      // 2nd column of cells I'm formatting
      } else if ( 2 == i ) {
        d2Arr[j] = ["left"];
      }
    }
    tmpRange.setHorizontalAlignments( d2Arr );   
  }
```

So, basically, I had to make the assignment `d2Arr[index]=["some string"]` in order to build the multidimensional array I was looking for. Since the number of cells I wanted to format can change from sheet to sheet, I wanted it generalized. The case I was working out required a 15-dimension array. Assigning a 1-D array to elements in a 1-D array ended up making the 15-D array I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Array.apply

```
        Array.apply(0, Array(ARRAY_SIZE)).map((row, rowIndex) => {
            return Array.apply(0, Array(ARRAY_SIZE)).map((column, columnIndex) => {
                return null;
            });
        });`
```