# My 2D table-building function in js won't work correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am building Tetris. I have figured out how to build a HTML table out of a two-dimensional array. However, normal Tetris is played in a ten-by-twenty grid. I am having troubles creating the inner arrays. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649729/dynamically-create-a-two-dimensional-javascript-array), but all of the answers don't make sense to me, are based around jQuery, or I can't tell the difference. The code doesn't result in an error. It outputs an empty array, when it should output a length-three array. (This is to test the code.) Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
function array(x, text) {
    var toBuild = [];
    for (var i; i < x-1; i++) {toBuild.push(text); }
    console.log(toBuild);
    return toBuild;
}
console.log(array(3, "hello"));
```

Comment: What is your expected output. Is it a nested 10 by 20 array?

Comment: No. Edited my post to clarify

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing in a `10` instead of a `3`? Also once you initialize i to zero you will also want to make the boolean part of the for loop `i < x`.

Comment: Sorry, some things got lost in making an MRE. I should clarify: It's a test, not actually doing what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you are not initializing the `i` in your for loop. You should assign it to `0`.

If you want your code to output an array o length `10` then you should pass `10` to your function and there is not to use `x-1`. You should use `x`

```js
function array(x, text) {
    var toBuild = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {toBuild.push(text); }
    console.log(toBuild);
    return toBuild;
}
console.log(array(10, "hello"));
```

The more fancy way of doing the same this is to use `fill`

```js
const array = (x, text) => Array(x).fill(text)
console.log(array(10, "hello"));
```

Comment: I will in four minutes